# Sonarqube 6.7 getting ping response from JVM and suddenly stopping on AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sonarqube

Sonarqube is not starting on aws. I am using a remote PostgreSQL database for sonar, however sonar works fine when i start it locally on my windows machine using the same configurations. 
I am using sonarqube 6.7, but i have tried with 6.6 as well. I am getting the same error.
I changed the logging level to debug in wrapper.conf and this is the output i got on aws:

```
            Running SonarQube...
            wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
            wrapper  | Using tick timer.
            wrapperp | server listening on port 32000.
            wrapper  | Command[0] : java
            wrapper  | Command[1] : -Dsonar.wrapped=true
            wrapper  | Command[2] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
            wrapper  | Command[3] : -Xms8m
            wrapper  | Command[4] : -Xmx32m
            wrapper  | Command[5] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
            wrapper  | Command[6] : -classpath
            wrapper  | Command[7] : ../
            wrapper  | Command[8] : -Dwrapper.key=4VXP1SaL6A6VQM7x
            wrapper  | Command[9] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
            wrapper  | Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
            wrapper  | Command[11] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
            wrapper  | Command[12] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
            wrapper  | Command[13] : -Dwrapper.pid=6447
            wrapper  | Command[14] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
            wrapper  | Command[15] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
            wrapper  | Command[16] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
            wrapper  | Command[17] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
            wrapper  | Command[18] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
            wrapper  | Command[19] : org.sonar.application.App
            wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
            jvm 1    | WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e
            jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
            jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
            jvm 1    |
            jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
            jvm 1    | Running a 64-bit JVM.
            jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
            jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
            jvm 1    | Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
            jvm 1    | Loading native library failed: libwrapper-linux-x86-64.so  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-linux-x86-64 in java.library.path
            jvm 1    | Loaded native library: libwrapper.so
            jvm 1    | Calling native initialization method.
            jvm 1    | Inside native WrapperManager initialization method
            jvm 1    | Java Version   : 1.8.0_151-b12 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
            jvm 1    | Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
            jvm 1    |
            jvm 1    | Control event monitor thread started.
            jvm 1    | WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@37f8bb67, args[]) called by thread: main
            jvm 1    | Startup runner thread started.
            jvm 1    | Communications runner thread started.
            jvm 1    | Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
            jvm 1    | Opened Socket from 31000 to 32000
            jvm 1    | Send a packet KEY : 4VXP1SaL6A6VQM7x
            jvm 1    | handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31000])
            wrapperp | accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31000
            wrapperp | read a packet KEY : 4VXP1SaL6A6VQM7x
            wrapper  | Got key from JVM: 4VXP1SaL6A6VQM7x
            wrapperp | send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
            wrapperp | send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
            wrapperp | send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
            wrapper  | Start Application.
            wrapperp | send a packet START : start
            jvm 1    | Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
            jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
            jvm 1    | Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
            jvm 1    | PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
            jvm 1    | Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
            jvm 1    | Received a packet START : start
            jvm 1    | calling WrapperListener.start()
            jvm 1    | Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
            jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
            jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
            jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
            jvm 1    | 2017.12.14 03:33:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /home/jisys/system/sonarqube-6.7/temp
            jvm 1    | 2017.12.14 03:33:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
            jvm 1    | 2017.12.14 03:33:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/sonarqube-6.7/elasticsearch]: /sonarqube-6.7/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/sonarqube-6.7/temp/conf/es
            jvm 1    | 2017.12.14 03:33:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
            jvm 1    | Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
            wrapperp | read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
            wrapper  | JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
            jvm 1    | 2017.12.14 03:33:21 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
            jvm 1    | 2017.12.14 03:33:21 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
            jvm 1    | Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
            jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
            jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
            jvm 1    | returned from WrapperListener.start()
            jvm 1    | Send a packet STARTED :
            jvm 1    | Startup runner thread stopped.
            wrapperp | read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
            wrapper  | JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
            wrapperp | read a packet STARTED :
            wrapper  | JVM signalled that it was started.
            wrapperp | send a packet PING : ping
            jvm 1    | Received a packet PING : ping
            jvm 1    | Send a packet PING : ok
            wrapperp | read a packet PING : ok
            wrapper  | Got ping response from JVM
            jvm 1    | 2017.12.14 03:33:24 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
            jvm 1    | 2017.12.14 03:33:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
            jvm 1    | 2017.12.14 03:33:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
            jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
            jvm 1    | WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
            jvm 1    | Send a packet STOP : 0
            wrapperp | read a packet STOP : 0
            wrapper  | JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
            wrapper  | wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
            wrapper  | Sending stop signal to JVM
            wrapperp | send a packet STOP : NULL
            jvm 1    | Received a packet STOP :
            jvm 1    | Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
            jvm 1    | calling listener.stop()
            jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: stop(0)
            jvm 1    | returned from listener.stop() -> 0
            jvm 1    | shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
            jvm 1    | Send a packet STOPPED : 0
            wrapperp | read a packet STOPPED : 0
            wrapper  | JVM signalled that it was stopped.
            jvm 1    | Closing socket.
            wrapperp | socket read no code (closed?).
            wrapperp | server listening on port 32001.
            jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
            jvm 1    | Server daemon shut down
            wrapper  | JVM exited normally.
            wrapper  | Signal trapped.  Details:
            wrapper  |   signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
            wrapper  | Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
            wrapper  | JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
            wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that your ElasticSearch process did not start properly.

A few things to check:

a. Check the es.log to see if it shows any obvious errors.

b. Check sonar.search.port in the config, what have you set? Is that port free?

Comment: I found the issue in the es.log file.
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
I ran sonarqube as another user and it ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in the es.log file.
Elasticsearch was not running as the root user.I ran sonarqube as another user and it ran successfully.

I got this from the es.log file

java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root